# Is "Que tan?" slang for "How are you?"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, coloquialismos

I'm english and I'm starting to learn Spanish on my own. My boss is fluent in Spanish and she sometimes says to me in the morning,

```
Buenas días, que tan?
```

Or something similar along those lines. She said the appropriate response is good or fine or however you're feeling.

I've searched a lot but I cannot find anything talking about `que tan`. It just translates to `how` in Google Translate. Is it some sort of slang (for "how are you")? Or is it just a shortening of the phrase? What is the reasoning behind this saying?

Gracias!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct term is: **¿qué tal?**
This a very used term when you already said something: hola, ¿qué tal?; buenas tardes, ¿qué tal? etc.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find anything on it! I misheard what she said... Thank you!

Comment: Just a note to add that *¿qué tal?* is short for *¿qué tal estás?* (how are you?)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is not *qué ta**l***. *Qué ta**n*** is used differently.

Example:

> How big is Mexico City?
>
> ¿Qué tan grande es la ciudad de México?

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Note that "qué tal" is indeed what the OP wanted to ask, so it IS the correct answer. Nonetheless, it is worth noting that "qué tan" is also possible in Spanish, so thank you for the clarification.